# Copy hidden files in a directory to a directory without permission issue?

Tags: permissions, cp

I'm trying to copy all of the hidden files to a directory. The problem is I can't copy it into a new folder. I get `Permission denied` error. How do I fix this?

I used:

```
cp -rf /usr/include /cse220-p01
```

Comment: You don't have permission to write in `/cse220-p01`..try using `sudo`

Comment: What is your end goal here? in what way is /usr/include "hidden"?

Comment: Whats the output you're getting? Do you have permission to work down `/`? Are you sure your destination directory is placed in `/`?

Comment: The problem is that you don't have write access to the directory, so it is not letting you copy files there. One of the answers suggests using Sudo, but you claimed it was not working. This is most likely because your user is not listed in the sudoers file, meaning that you do not have permission to use sudo on this system. Long story short, it is giving you permission denied because you do not have permission. Contact the system admin for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your user does not have the permission to write in the directory you are trying to copy the file. You can use `root` account or try with `sudo -u "user" cp file path`.

[image]

Comment: I tried doing the sudo user but its telling me that its not a sudoers file. I'm pretty new to linux Is there anything else I can try to do to get permission?

Comment: can you put your command output here?